# ASP.NET C# CheckBox does not fire CheckedChanged event when unchecking

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, repeater

I have repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptResult" runat="server" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkShipStatus" runat="server"  EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode = "Enabled" AutoPostBack="True"  CommandName='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CT")%>'    OnCheckedChanged="chkShipStatus_CheckedChanged"  Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("SHIPPED")) ? true : false %>'  />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and

and call data from page_load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            DataTable dt = ap.GetDataTable(sql);
            rptResult.DataSource = dt;
            rptResult.DataBind();
         }
       //go there and finish when unchecd

    }
```

and here is my CheckedChanged event it call only when i cheched not firing when i unchecked it go to page_load(not incycle !postback)

```
     protected void chkShipStatus_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cb = (CheckBox)sender;
       //go there when i checked
         if (cb.Checked == true)
        {
            //go there when i checked

        }
        else
        {
           //never go in here when i uncheck
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just want to sent some data to codebehind

Comment: You have commented `//go there and finish when unchecked`. What does that mean, why is  code in `Page_Load` regarding the `unchecked` issue if you use `chkShipStatus_CheckedChanged`? Do you have omitted code?

Comment: that means when i unchech checkbox it doesnt call chkShipStatus_CheckedChanged but it go to page_load(maybe because of autopostnack true)

Comment: So it goes to `Page_Load`,  does not enter `GetDataTable` as desired(because of the `!IsPostBack`) but also doesn't enter the `chkShipStatus_CheckedChanged` which is not desired? Then i don't know why, the reason must be somewhere else. Is there relevant code that you have omitted?

Answer (score 1):

A `CheckBox` has no `CommandName` property so remove it

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkShipStatus" runat="server"  EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode = "Enabled" 
             AutoPostBack="True"        
             OnCheckedChanged="chkShipStatus_CheckedChanged"  
             Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("SHIPPED")) ? true : false %>'  
/>
```

if you want to know in which item the checkbox was you can use `NamingContainer`. Then use `repeaterItem.FindControl` to get another control in that `RepeaterItem`. So you could for example use a `HiddenField` to store the ID of the record.

```
protected void chkShipStatus_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem) cb.NamingContainer
    HiddenField hiddenID = (HiddenField) item.FindControl("HiddenID");
    string id = hiddenID.Value;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it is the answer for my question. The problem is when i unchecked it it dont call function chkShipStatus_CheckedChanged

Comment: it isnt answer for my question

Comment: @user3397383: what makes it not an answer of your question?

Comment: CheckBox does not fire CheckedChanged event when unchecking

Answer (score 0):

you say :

> it call only when i cheched not firing when i unchecked it go to page_load(not incycle !postback)

so what is the code in the load ??
it may has some code that prevents the uncheck process

Comment: thanks,  but i dont have any thing after if(!postback) in page load

Comment: and when you put a break point , does it say it's not loaded or can not be hitted ? try to clean or rebuild the solution
and another thing : try to right click in any place on the page and select Inspect element to watch the console it may help you with message or something

Comment: i did make break point and it go to page load and fineshed i dont have any think in pageload(it dont go if(!postback))

Answer (score 0):

If you have **SHIPPED** column values like 1 OR 0 then I recommend you to update below attribute of your checkbox control. I tried it and **chkShipStatus_CheckedChanged** event calling for me.

```
Checked='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("SHIPPED")) == "1" ? true : false %>'
```

Comment: it lost uncheck after autopostback

Comment: Please make your repeater viewstate enabled and then try.

Comment: i added but still same. the uncheck still lost after 2 s